# better linq union

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a datatable like this (example):

```
  
CurrentText  CurrentValue  OldText  OldValue  
--------------------------------------------  
Test1              1       OldTest1     1   
Test2              2       OldTest2     2
```

I want to do a union so the result looks like this

```
Text  Value  IsCurrent   
Test1   1       true   
Test2   2       true   
OldTest1 1      false
OldTest2 2      false
```

How I do this right now:

```
 var lst = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new MyClass
            {
                 Text = x.Field<string>("CurrentText"), 
                 Value = x.Field<string>("CurrentValue"),  
                 IsCurrent=true
            })
             .Union(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new MyClass
             {
                 Text = x.Field<string>("OldText"), 
                 Value = x.Field<string>("OldValue"),  
                 IsCurrent=false
             })
             ).Distinct().ToList();
```

The only question I have: is there a better/faster approach?

Comment: It appears to me your starting from `dt` and projecting it into two variations on `IsCurrent` and then unioning them.  It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, since both sequences would be identical, except that one set would have `true` and the other `false` for `IsCurrent`.  Is that what you actually trying to do?

Comment: @KirkWoll, No, sequences are going to be different because I'm trying to union different columns. So, basically I want to append two column to another two columns.

Comment: That's fine, but you should really modify your code to illustrate that distinction.  Right now I could provide an answer that would be cleaner, but I doubt it would be helpful.  I really need to see how you're actualy creating the disparate sequences.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I think I don't follow you. the distinction is that my first dataset selects: `x.Field<string>("CurrentText")` and `x.Field<string>("CurrentValue")` while the second dataset selects: `x.Field<string>("OldText")` and  `x.Field<string>("OldValue")`

Comment: Apologies, you are absolutely right.  I missed that on my first scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really know what you need to accomplish, but for code readability, perhaps creating a concrete IEnuerable class would help someone to understand and extend in future ?

```
   private static IEnumerable<Tuple<String,String>> GetPairs(ref DataTable dtr)
    {
      var CurrentPairs = dtr.AsEnumerable().Select(t => Tuple.Create
                                                  (
                                                    t.Field<String>("CurrentText"),
                                                    t.Field<String>("CurrentValue")
                                                  ));
      var NewPairs = dtr.AsEnumerable().Select(t => Tuple.Create
                                                  (
                                                    t.Field<String>("OldText"),
                                                    t.Field<String>("OldValue")
                                                  ));

      return CurrentPairs.Union(NewPairs);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you projecting into tuples?  The OP's original projection into anonymous types will work as intended.  (two anonymous types in the same assembly with the same properties declared with the same types and in the same order will be the same actual `System.Type`)

Comment: I'm using tuples because is quick and easy, and you don't need to write class to put things together, and dealing with datatable which is not a concrete implementation. Seems to me the OP want to different  different type of Pair values so for readability is important to my opinion. Anonymous is fast but sometime is nasty.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that the reason you used it was to allow it to be returned from a method.  Apologies.